# Yocto kernel config propagation

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

In my Yocto system, I have a layer defining a bunch of patches on the linux kernel, as well as a file "defconfig" containing kernel configuration. When I modify this file, changes are reflected in the image I build.

However, a few changes are being overruled and I have a hard time figuring out how or where. I do find a bunch of defconfig files in other layers, but is there any easy way to figure out which ones are applied and in what order?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not other defconfigs that overrule your configuration (at least not in an even only remotely sane setup), but configuration fragments ([creating fragments](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#creating-config-fragments)). You can find out what happens exactly like that:

```
bitbake -e virtual/kernel | less
```

(you can of course choose another pager, or redirect to a file for additional processing)

And look for:

```
KERNEL_FEATURES
```

--> here you can find a list of kernel configuration fragments in the form of .scc files that are applied to your build

```
SRC_URI
```

--> this should mention the path to your defconfig file, and no second one.

Please note that this description only holds entirely true for setups that include a kernel defconfig. If you are working without one, things can be different.